# Что такое AIDL и для чего он нужен?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-service

Что такое AIDL и для чего он нужен? Понятно, что он связан с сервисами, но что конкретно он делает мне не понятно. Как я понял из [документации](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/aidl.html) AIDL нужен для взаимодействия сервисов (возможно, что я не прав). Приведите, пожалуйста, пример использования и код.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AIDL

В буквальном переводе – язык описания интерфейсов Android. Используется для описания композиции и декомпозиции Java объектов в примитивы ОС для непосредственно передачи между процесами.
AIDL файлы очень похожи на стандартные интерфейсы в java за исключением:

1. Импортировать нужно даже те aidl файлы, которые находятся в том же пакете.
2. Ключевое слово oneway в декларации void метода означает что метод будет вызван асинхронно (клиент не дожидается его выполнения).
3. Использовать можно только примитивы, String, List и Parcelable классы, объявленные в других aidl файлах.

С помощью AIDL автоматически генерируется java код для генерации stub’ов.

Подробнее: [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/139432/)